# not getting string value while type casting object from DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, object, casting

I am fetching values from table and storing 1st value into "yr" and 2nd value into some other variable but I am not getting proper value while casting object into string.

```
List<Object[]> listObject = ddeffectiverepository.getDetails("P-to-P", fullImpacted); 
String yr = listObject.get(0)[0].toString();
```

my repository:

```
@Query("select ed.year, ed.fullimpact from EffectiveImpact ed where ed.part = ?1 and ed.rgn = ?2")
public List<Object[]> getDetails(String part, String rgn);
```

but while debugging i am getting values into **listObject** but it is not storing first value into **yr**. Instead of it is storing some object like "[Ljava.lang.Object;@2d8383cd"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not casting object coming from DB into string

Comment: List<Object> getDetails()... use a specific class at generic, instead of object

Comment: i didn't quite understand you question

Comment: @AdityaRewari need to use only List of objects

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan i want to store object value coming from database into string

Comment: @Deepak why your database can return string in the first place, show me the input and output , and give a concrete example , and please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Instead of holding values in Object, hold them into Object Array.
Here is changed code:

repository:

```
@Query("select ed.year, ed.fullimpact from EffectiveImpact ed where ed.part = ?1 and ed.rgn = ?2")
public List<Object[]> getDetails(String part, String rgn);
```

Service/business layer :

```
List<Object[]> listObject = ddeffectiverepository.getDetails("P-to-P", fullImpacted); 
String yr = listObject.get(0)[0].toString();
```

Comment: I changed with List<Object[]> but while storing first value into yr, i getting object like [Ljava.lang.Object;@2d8383cd" this in yr

Comment: what is source code of entity class EffectiveImpact ?

Comment: this is a model class(entity).

Comment: Entity
Table(name= "effective_implementation")
class EffectiveImpact implements Serializable {

Id
Column(name= "years")
private String part;

Column(name = "region")
private String region;

getter and setters